# Error when add multiple waypoints to Leaflet

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, leaflet

The code works fine for two waypoints on an ionic v1 app, but if I add more than two, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
at o.LatLng.distanceTo (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js:6:14158)
at e._extendToWaypoints (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js:3751:18)
at e.initialize (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js:3699:10)
at new e (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js:6:2539)
at Object.line (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js:3329:16)
at e.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/services/Maps.js:461:35)
at e.fireEvent (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js:6:4952)
at e.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/leaflet-routing-machine-3.2.5/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js:2907:13)
at e._routeDone (file:///android_asset/www/lib/lrm-mapbox/lrm-mapbox.js:289:20)
at e.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/lrm-mapbox/lrm-mapbox.js:248:22)
```

The strange thing is that this code where working well a few months ago, but suddenly it started to fail. The problematic code is this:

```
function getRoute() {
    var r = L.Routing.control({

      waypoints: waypoints,
      router: new L.Routing.Mapbox(Config.mapBoxApiKey,
        {
          serviceUrl: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/directions/',
          timeout: 30 * 1000,
          profile: 'mapbox.' + tipo
        }
      ),
      lineOptions: {
        styles: styles
      },
      fitSelectedRoutes: false,
      routeWhileDragging: false,
      createMarker: function () {
        return null;
      }

    });

    return r;
  }

  var control = getRoute();
  var routeLayer = L.layerGroup([control]); <---- HERE I GET THE ERROR
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Leaflet, [Controls](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control) are different from [Layers](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer).

In particular, you cannot make them children of a [Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup).

As shown in [Leaflet Routing Machine plugin home page](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/), you just need to use the `addTo()` method to add your Control to the map:

```js
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: waypoints
}).addTo(map);
```

In your precise case:

```js
getRoute().addTo(map);
```